# Custom paging in a ReportViewer report

Tags: reportviewer, custom-paging

I have a report which is a list of Order form. For each order form, I would like the paging to be page x of y, where x is the page number of the current order and y and the total page for this order.

All orders are on different pages (no two orders on the same page)

If I can't have page x of y, I would like just page x.

I know I could just generate the reports multiple times for each order, but it seems my boss doesn't like the idea..

Is this even possible and if so how ?

thanks,

Comment: You should probably tell us which reporting technology you are using.

Comment: It's reportViwer (2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this procedure:

1-Drag a textbox to end of each group(of orderid)

2-In expression of textbox write: =GetPage(orderid)

3-In code of report page write a vb code that have a counetpage number and  when orderid was  changed, reset a counetpage and finally return counetpage

Comment: There is nothing like GetPage in the reportviwer I am using... Are you refering to some other technology ?

Comment: yes, in report properties exist a tab with name 'code' that you can write vb code

Comment: GetPage() is your custome page that must implemented according to line 3

Comment: OK,but I don't really see how this would work... I mean, OK so I can do code in VB, but how can I get the information about which group I'm on which page and so on... Plus this would appear at the end of the group, not the page.

Comment: you must pass orderid to getpage method and store in a variable and in next call of method with new orderid, check if storedOrderid equals with neworderid? if yes counter++ else counter=1 and storedOrderid=newstoredorderid; return counter.